# Trying to understand how many functions there are from A to B.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to understand why there are $B^A$ functions from $A$ to $B$. If $A=${$a,b$} and $B=${$1,2,3$} then the functions from $A$ to $B$ are $f(a)=1$, $f(b)=1$, $f(a)=2$, $f(b)=2$, $f(a)=3$, $f(b)=3$. If this is correct then there are only 6 functions.

Am I going about things incorrectly?

Comment: What about $f(a) = 1, f(b) = 2$?

Comment: These aren't necessarily separate functions...you can have $f(a)=1$ and $f(b)=1$ with $f$ as the same function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only restriction for $f$ to be a function is that there must be exactly $1$ output for each input.  What $a$ can map to is completely independent of what $b$ can map to.  Hence, $a$ can map to $1$, $2$, or $3$, and likewise for $b$.

$\Longrightarrow$ there are $3 \times 3 = 9$ possibilities.

Note that this is the same as the age-old combinatorics question "How many ways are there to distribute $r$ distinguishable balls into $n$ distinguishable boxes?".  The question changes slightly if you add certain restrictions like injectivity or surjectivity.  [This link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way) might be of interest to you.

Comment: I still don't understand how that gives 9  possibilities. Can you give an example.

Comment: Suppose $f(a) = 1$.  Then the possibilities for $f(b)$ are $1, 2$, or $3$.  Next, suppose $f(a) = 2$.  Then again, $f(b) = 1, 2$, or $3$.  Finally, if $f(a) = 3$, we again have $3$ possibilities for $f(b)$.

Comment: Ahh, I think I get it. Thank you so much! If I wanted to list one of the functions would $f(a)=1$ be sufficient, or do I have to also give $f(b)=1$?

Comment: You would have to specify the values for both $f(a)$ and $f(b)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The function does not have to be injective. For each element in your domain, you have $|B|$ choices for it to map to.

Answer (score 0):

Fix an element in  $A$, see that it can be mapped to any element in $B$. So you have |$B$| possibilities for each element of $A$. now count the total possibilities as the element varies in $A$ also.

Answer (score 0):

The restriction on function $f:A\rightarrow B$ is that every element in $A$ should be mapped to some element in $B$ and every element should have a unique mapping i.e. no element in $A$ should be mapped to $2$ different elements in $B$. However, there is no such restriction on $B$.
So for every element in B, you have to choose $0$ to $n(A)$ elements. So you have $n(A)$ for each element in $B$. That gives us $n(A)$ choices for $n(B)$ elements i.e. a total of $n(B)^{n(A)}$ choices